# Qt macdeployqt - crash after using

Tags: macos, qt, macdeployqt

When I run application after using macdeploy my application crashed.
I trying use SDK 4.8.5 and 5.2... but nothing to changes..

**Command:**
Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt Application.app -verbose=2

**Log:**

```
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/MacOS/Application") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtSvg.framework/Versions/5/QtSvg" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/5/QtSvg" 
Log: copy: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtSvg.framework/Resources" "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Resources" 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets" 
Log: copy: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Resources" "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Resources" 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui" 
Log: copy: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Resources" "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Resources" 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore" 
Log: copy: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Resources" "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Resources" 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL" 
Log: copy: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Resources" "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Resources" 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml" 
Log: copy: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtXml.framework/Resources" "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Resources" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying plugins from "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins" 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport" 
Log: copy: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Resources" "Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Resources" 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/printsupport/libcocoaprintersupport.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/printsupport/libcocoaprintersupport.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/printsupport/libcocoaprintersupport.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/accessible/libqtaccessiblewidgets.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/accessible/libqtaccessiblewidgets.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/accessible/libqtaccessiblewidgets.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqgif.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqgif.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/imageformats/libqico.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqico.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqico.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqmng.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqmng.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg_debug.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqsvg_debug.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqsvg_debug.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqtga.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqtga.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib") 
Log: copied: "/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.dylib" 
Log: to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqwbmp.dylib" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying Qt frameworks found inside: ("Application.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqwbmp.dylib") 
Log: Created configuration file: "Application.app/Contents/Resources/qt.conf" 
Log: This file sets the plugin search path to "Application.app/Contents/PlugIns"
```

**Application output to console:**

```
Tests:~ ltise$ /Developer/Projects/Tests/build-Application-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit2-Release/qt_debug/Application.app/Contents/MacOS/Application ; exit;
("/Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins") 
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1039057e0) is not the object's thread (0x1039079f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1039057e0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1039057e0) is not the object's thread (0x1039079f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1039057e0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1039057e0) is not the object's thread (0x1039079f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1039057e0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1039057e0) is not the object's thread (0x1039079f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1039057e0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
objc[47743]: Class NotificationReceiver is implemented in both /Developer/Projects/Tests/build-Application-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit2-Release/qt_debug/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets and /Users/ltise/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1039057e0) is not the object's thread (0x1039079f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1039057e0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1039057e0) is not the object's thread (0x1039079f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1039057e0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1039057e0) is not the object's thread (0x1039079f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1039057e0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1039057e0) is not the object's thread (0x1039079f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1039057e0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
Support formats: ("bmp", "pbm", "pgm", "png", "ppm", "xbm", "xpm") 
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1039057e0) is not the object's thread (0x1039079f0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1039057e0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa".

Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Abort trap: 6
logout

[Process completed]
```

**Check otool:**
otool -L Application.app/contents/macos/application

**Log:**

```
Application.app/contents/macos/Application:
/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Versions/A/GLUT (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/5/QtSvg (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 60.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

**Crash Report on running:**

```
Process: Application [45439]
Path: /Developer/Projects/Vectools/build-Application-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit2-Release/qt_debug/Application.app/Contents/MacOS/Application
Identifier: @BUNDLEIDENTIFIER@
Version: ???
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [169]
Responsible: Application [45439]
User ID: 503

Date/Time: 2014-02-02 21:38:19.006 +0400
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
Report Version: 11
Anonymous UUID: 7B93716C-BCAF-BAA9-71E1-51752259B530

Sleep/Wake UUID: CB2DC327-2013-416E-B21F-0655A3570A07

Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff89f47866 __pthread_kill + 10
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8c28635c pthread_kill + 92
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff91598bba abort + 125
3 QtCore 0x0000000100ed4b69 0x100ebb000 + 105321
4 QtCore 0x0000000100ed51a1 QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 161
5 QtGui 0x0000000100a9a5cd QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() + 4333
6 QtGui 0x0000000100a9a5eb QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() + 27
7 QtCore 0x00000001010cc778 QCoreApplication::init() + 104
8 QtCore 0x00000001010cc6e7 QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(QCoreApplicationPrivate&) + 39
9 QtGui 0x0000000100a9850e QGuiApplication::QGuiApplication(QGuiApplicationPrivate&) + 14
10 QtWidgets 0x00000001004c28be QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) + 206
11 @BUNDLEIDENTIFIER@ 0x000000010012b85a main + 618
12 @BUNDLEIDENTIFIER@ 0x0000000100004524 start + 52

Thread 1:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff89f47e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8c286f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8c289fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff89f48662 kevent64 + 10
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff92c0243d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff92c02152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff89f47e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8c286f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8c289fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x0000000000000000 rbx: 0x00007fff7a579310 rcx: 0x00007fff5fbff638 rdx: 0x0000000000000000
rdi: 0x0000000000000707 rsi: 0x0000000000000006 rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff660 rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff638
r8: 0x00000001030020a0 r9: 0x0000000000000000 r10: 0x0000000008000000 r11: 0x0000000000000206
r12: 0x00007fff5fbff928 r13: 0x00007fff5fbffc20 r14: 0x0000000000000006 r15: 0x00007fff5fbff8f8
rip: 0x00007fff89f47866 rfl: 0x0000000000000206 cr2: 0x0000000100d6ece5

Logical CPU: 0
Error Code: 0x02000148
Trap Number: 133


Binary Images:
0x100000000 - 0x1002c7fff +@BUNDLEIDENTIFIER@ (???) <EE932156-8537-39B5-9537-50FD73AAEB62> /Developer/Projects/Vectools/build-Application-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit2-Release/qt_debug/Application.app/Contents/MacOS/Application
0x10039a000 - 0x1003daff7 com.apple.glut (3.6.0 - GLUT-3.6.0) <87683C90-4303-3561-9CC8-5772FDEC16F0> /System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Versions/A/GLUT
0x10044e000 - 0x100485ff7 +QtSvg (5.2) <03531661-9BA9-3B37-B1D5-EE422B1EB00B> /Developer/Projects/Vectools/build-Application-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit2-Release/qt_debug/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/5/QtSvg
0x10049a000 - 0x100951ff7 +QtWidgets (5.2) <EF8840B8-A258-3110-8B39-EDBE4E708D87> /Developer/Projects/Vectools/build-Application-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit2-Release/qt_debug/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
0x100a77000 - 0x100df6ff7 +QtGui (5.2) <1D90F282-6151-3035-8878-C6AFB7E54E1D> /Developer/Projects/Vectools/build-Application-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit2-Release/qt_debug/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
0x100ebb000 - 0x1013b3ff7 +QtCore (5.2) <823F3C93-3ADF-3CD3-992D-06097B4F44E5> 

....................

/Developer/Projects/Vectools/build-Application-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit2-Release/qt_debug/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
0x101437000 - 0x10147efff +QtOpenGL (5.2) <5CCDC659-2305-35DA-95F6-997237B57E28> /Developer/Projects/Vectools/build-Application-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit2-nwind.dylib

....................

0x7fff9782a000 - 0x7fff97afefc7 com.apple.vImage (7.0 - 7.0) <D241DBFA-AC49-31E2-893D-EAAC31890C90> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x7fff97b6c000 - 0x7fff97b95fff com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 208) <A539A058-BA57-35EE-AA08-D0B0E835127D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x7fff97b96000 - 0x7fff97bf9ff7 com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.13 - 1.13) <F05F4149-981B-380B-8F50-51CE804BBB89> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration

External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 1
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 22215290
thread_create: 2
thread_set_state: 13573

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=211.9M resident=211.8M(100%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=92K(0%)
Writable regions: Total=51.0M written=1344K(3%) resident=1804K(3%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=49.2M(97%)

REGION TYPE VIRTUAL
=========== =======
Kernel Alloc Once 4K
MALLOC 40.4M
MALLOC (admin) 32K
STACK GUARD 56.0M
Stack 9304K
VM_ALLOCATE 328K
__DATA 22.0M
__IMAGE 528K
__LINKEDIT 72.6M
__TEXT 139.3M
__UNICODE 544K
mapped file 22.5M
shared memory 4K
=========== =======
TOTAL 363.2M

Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B08, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.9 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK7559GSXF, 750,16 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R UJ-8A8, 448,6 MB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: This part of the bt: `4 QtCore 0x0000000100ed51a1 QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 161
5 QtGui 0x0000000100a9a5cd QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration()` suggests there is a message on the console before the application aborts. I’d assume something about a missing platform plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both Qt versions installed at the same time, it may give you some problems.  I think I've had to give up on having both installed at the same time, because of some of the trouble it would give me during deployment.

And then it you have homebrew installed and it has a version of Qt, it can also get in the way on your Path, when the mac deploy tool is running.

Hope that helps.